# Namespaced routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I must be missing something with this rather trivial routes implementation in Rails 3.

I have a namespaced route like so:

```
namespace 'dashboard' do
  get 'download', to: "Index#download"
end
```

If I run `rake routes` I see:

```
dashboard_download  GET  /dashboard/download(.:format) {:action=>"download", :controller=>"dashboard/Index"}
```

The URL is super, that's exactly what I want (and will have many more matches in the namespace), but the controller is wrong. It should just be `Index`, not `dashboard/Index`.

Is there any way of fixing this?
Or is that the wrong way to implement that style of route?

Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove the module prefix do this:

```
scope '/dashboard' do
  get 'download', to: "Index#download"
end
```

You can find more information and alternatives [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing).